# Statistical Analysis of X-Wing Game Dice

Tags: c#, object-oriented, random, simulation

I was in a discussion about mechanics of the X-Wing miniatures game where we were discussing a couple of the ways to improve attacks and I put together this small C# console application to determine which method was move effective. The program rolls a specified number of the game's attack dice and then compares if a Focus token (converting all dice rolled onto to the Focus face to hits) or a Target Lock (re-rolling any number of dice) would result in a better attack, on average. It does this for a range of number of attack dice being rolled, and for a configurable number of trials.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace XWingDice
{
    class Program
    {
        // Bounds for number of dice to test
        const int MIN_DICE = 1;
        const int MAX_DICE = 5;

        // Number of trials for each number of dice
        const int NUM_TRIALS = 1000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            stopwatch.Start();

            List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

            for (int numDice = MIN_DICE; numDice <= MAX_DICE; numDice++)
            {
                Result result = new Result(numDice, NUM_TRIALS);

                List<Die> dice = new List<Die>();

                // Initialize a list of dice for the current number of dice
                for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++)
                    dice.Add(new Die());

                // Conduct the trials
                for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIALS; i++)
                {
                    // Get the initial dice rolls
                    dice.RollDice();

                    #region Focus

                    // Clone the list of dice
                    List<Die> focusDice = dice.CloneDice();

                    // Convert the focus dies to hits
                    focusDice.UseFocus();

                    #endregion Focus

                    #region Target Lock

                    // Clone the list of dice
                    List<Die> targetLockDice = dice.CloneDice();

                    // Get the current hits and crits
                    List<Die> goodDice = targetLockDice.Where(d => d.state == DieState.Crit || d.state == DieState.Hit).ToList();

                    // Get the focus and miss dice
                    List<Die> badDice = targetLockDice.Where(d => d.state == DieState.Focus || d.state == DieState.Miss).ToList();

                    // Re-roll the focus and miss dice
                    badDice.RollDice();

                    // Recombine the intial dice and the re-rolled
                    targetLockDice = goodDice.Union(badDice).ToList();

                    #endregion Target Lock

                    // Get the scores 
                    decimal focusScore = focusDice.ScoreDice();
                    decimal targetLockScore = targetLockDice.ScoreDice();

                    // Increment the result object with the trial result
                    if (focusScore == targetLockScore)
                        result.Tie++;
                    else if (focusScore > targetLockScore)
                        result.FocusBetter++;
                    else
                        result.TargetLockBetter++;
                }

                // Trial complete, add the result to the list
                results.Add(result);
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            // Write out the results
            foreach (Result result in results)
                Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.WriteLine("Completed in {0} seconds.", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Die.cs**

```
using System;

namespace XWingDice
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Possible dice faces
    /// </summary>
    enum DieState
    {
        Crit,
        Hit,
        Focus,
        Miss
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an X-Wing attack die
    /// </summary>
    class Die : ICloneable
    {
        // Dice face values for scoring of roles
        const decimal CRIT_VALUE = 1.1m;
        const decimal HIT_VALUE = 1;
        const decimal FOCUS_VALUE = 0;
        const decimal MISS_VALUE = 0;

        static Random random;

        static Die()
        {
            random = new Random();
        }

        // Current face of the die
        public DieState state { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls the die to select a new face value for the die
        /// </summary>
        public void RollDie()
        {
            int rand = random.Next(0, 8);

            // A die has the following faces:
            //  1 Crit
            //  3 Hits
            //  2 Focus Eyes
            //  2 Misses
            switch (rand)
            {
                case 0:
                    state = DieState.Crit;
                    break;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    state = DieState.Hit;
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                    state = DieState.Focus;
                    break;
                case 6:
                case 7:
                    state = DieState.Miss;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid face value in Die.RollDie");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the score based on the current face value
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Decimal value for score of current face</returns>
        public decimal Score()
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case DieState.Crit:
                    return CRIT_VALUE;
                case DieState.Hit:
                    return HIT_VALUE;
                case DieState.Focus:
                    return FOCUS_VALUE;
                case DieState.Miss:
                    return MISS_VALUE;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid die state in Die.Score");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a Focus die to a Hit
        /// </summary>
        public void UseFocus()
        {
            if (state == DieState.Focus)
                state = DieState.Hit;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clones the current die object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>New Die object</returns>
        public object Clone()
        {
            Die newDie = new Die();
            newDie.state = state;
            return newDie;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result.cs**

```
namespace XWingDice
{
    class Result
    {
        private int dieCount;
        private int totalRolls;
        public int FocusBetter { get; set; } = 0;
        public int TargetLockBetter { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Tie { get; set; } = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new result object to store the result of the trials for certain number of attack die
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dieCount">Current number of attack die being rolled</param>
        /// <param name="totalRolls">Number of trials used</param>
        public Result(int dieCount, int totalRolls)
        {
            this.dieCount = dieCount;
            this.totalRolls = totalRolls;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts result to hum readable format
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            // If tie, return such a result
            if (FocusBetter == TargetLockBetter)
                return string.Format("{0} die: Tie after {1} runs", dieCount, totalRolls);

            // Record better values for reuse
            bool focusWon = FocusBetter > TargetLockBetter;
            string winnerName = focusWon ? "Focus" : "Target Lock";
            int winnerCount = focusWon ? FocusBetter : TargetLockBetter;

            return string.Format("{0} die: {1} wins with {2} rolls better out of {3} rolls with {4} ties", dieCount, winnerName, winnerCount, totalRolls, Tie);
        }
    }
}
```

**ListExtensions.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace XWingDice
{
    static class ListExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls all the dice in a list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dice">List of dice to roll</param>
        public static void RollDice(this List<Die> dice)
        {
            dice.ForEach(d => d.RollDie());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Computes the score of a list of dice
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dice">List of dice to be scored</param>
        /// <returns>Score of the list of dice</returns>
        public static decimal ScoreDice(this List<Die> dice)
        {
            return dice.Sum(d => d.Score());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uses the focus token on each die in the list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dice">List of dice to use the focus token on</param>
        public static void UseFocus(this List<Die> dice)
        {
            dice.ForEach(d => d.UseFocus());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clones a list of dice
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dice">List of dice to clone</param>
        /// <returns>New list of dice</returns>
        public static List<Die> CloneDice(this List<Die> dice)
        {
            return dice.Select(d => (Die)d.Clone()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I will gladly take any comments about standard practices but in particular I am curious about a few things:

- Does my code fit an OOP design well? Am I using too many or too few classes to properly encapsulate the functionality? Would taking a more functional approach have been more appropriate?
- Are the list extension methods worthwhile? Is this good DRY programming or do I just like extension methods too much?
- I do plan on trying to make the programming multi-threaded at some point so that the different number of dice trials occur simultaneously and so multiple dice rolls can occur at once. Are there any suggestions for cleaning this code up so that transition is easier?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public int FocusBetter { get; set; } = 0;
> ...
> ```

You don't need to initialize your `int` properties to zero. They are `default(int)` (zero) by default.

You implement `ICloneable` but if your only use of it is as shown above, then you really don't need the interface so can create your own `Clone()` method which returns your actual object type, rather than returning `object` and then casting it.

I really dislike the extension methods. It feels wrong to have extension methods that perform application logic on a `List` containing objects of your type. Maybe it's just me. But I would much rather see you either implementing your own collection object and then expose the methods from that object, or have those methods part of whatever class holds the lists.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will be looking into making my own "list" object for the dice to remove the extensions. I did have a question about implementing `ICloneable`. I know I don't need the method returning an `object` in my case, but in general when making the implementation, do people typically add a second method returning the type it is implemented on?

Comment: @EvanFrisch I've never implemented that interface so can't say. But if you are using something that requires `ICloneable`, and that's the only thing that does cloning, then there's no point implementing a version that returns your type, as it will never be called. In your case though you seem to want clone functionality but (presumably) do not need to pass the object to anything that requires the actual `ICloneable` interface. Therefore in this case it makes more sense to only implement a method to perform a clone with a return of its type. Or create an `ICloneable<T>` interface if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest thing that strikes me about your solution is the massive over creation of objects.

Think about how you would go about testing your theory by hand. You would roll ONE die and keep three running score totals. One for normal score, one for if you converted the Focus the a hit, and one for if you rerolled Target Locks.

Your current solution is the equivalent of rolling at least 1 million dice and leaving them on the floor. You then get another 1 million dice and manually set them to match the 1 million you've already rolled. You then pick out certain sets of those 1 million dice and start adding up scores, and re-rolling them.

This is very inefficient use of time and memory when really all you need is one die. The garbage collector has to keep track of these several million dice and the CPU has to constantly fetch new memory locations when checking the results (the equivalent of you hunting around your floor). You are also forced to write helper methods to add and sum all these dice which makes your code rather confusing to follow.

Try a more functional solution where you roll one die and keep running totals. I would bet you could shrink your code by 80% at least and it would run way faster.

ps. I would agree with eurotrash that extension methods are designed to extend the class they are attached to. Methods relating to dice rolls belong in a die class, or program method. Not attached to a generic list.

Comment: I honestly didn't think about how many objects I was creating. I can definitely lower the number of dice objects being used, thanks for that input.

Answer (score 2):

On the whole I quite liked reading your code, the way you'd broken down the problem seemed to make sense and overall it was very readable.  There are a few things that came to mind:

**Extension Methods**

I'm not really sure how I feel about the way you've used them.  For the most part, it feels pretty clean and they replace creating another class to model the dice collection.  It has created a bit of a separation in the logic though, at the moment your `Main` does this:

```
List<Die> goodDice = targetLockDice.Where(d => d.state == DieState.Crit || d.state == DieState.Hit).ToList();
```

It feels like if you're going down the extension method approach, maybe this selection belongs in another extension method.  That way related logic is still in the same class, even if it's as extension methods.

**#region**

I'm not a huge fan of regions, however they can be a useful tool for grouping related methods together.  If you get to the point where you feel like you need to declare a region within an individual function (which is what you're doing in `Main`), then to me it's a big flag saying you're missing a method.

**static construction**

You don't really need a static constructor for the `Die` class, you could simply construct `Random` when you declare it:

```
static readonly Random random = new Random();
```

**Thread Safety**

You said you are thinking about making your application threaded in the future.  At the moment, you're sharing a single instance of `Random` amongst all of your `Die`.  This is good in a single threaded environment since it gives an even distribution, however [Random isn't threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109361/592182).  So you're going to need to build some kind of protection around it.  Breaking the `Main` logic up into focused methods / classes will also help prepare it for concurrency.

**Bracing**

You consistently don't uses braces around single line `if`s and `for`s.  If this is going to be a personal project, then that's fine.  If you're going to let other people work on it, then as I'm sure you already know, some people don't like this style.  It's more likely that bugs will be introduced during maintenance by people misreading which statement they're working on (although less so in modern IDEs).

**Readonly**

Where you're only setting the value of a member field during construction and not changing it, you should consider marking the fields as readonly.  This can help with some compiler optimisations.

```
private readonly int dieCount;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! I have a question about the Random out of the static constructor. I've had some problems before with declaring multiple Random objects but then they all return the same pattern of numbers. Is that not an issue in this case or was that likely something specific I was doing wrong? I went the static route so I could guarantee they would all be using the same Random and thus all moving along the same path.

Comment: @EvanFrisch I haven't removed the staticness, I'm simply suggesting that you can inline the construction, so you don't need to do it in a constructor function.

Comment: just a note to _static construction vs declaration + new_: with simple objects it makes no difference but as soon as there is even a slightest possibility that the constructor might throw an exception it's better to use a static constructor because otherwise you won't be able to trace what happened and the app just crashes. with a static constructor visual studio will stop at the line where the exception has been thrown if it's enabled in the debugger settings.

Comment: @t3chb0t I tend to avoid static where possible, so haven't encountered that. My assumption would have been that VS would break on the declaration/failing constructor. Thanks for the insight.